# rewriting euler-totient function in haskell

Tags: haskell

If I wanted to write the totient function, one way (assuming that we have a `primeFactors` function, that returns a list including multiplicity.) is the following:

```
totient:: Integer->Integer
totient m = product [(p - 1)  | p <- primeFactors m]
```

which would be fine, but there is another way to do this, by taking the product over (1-1/p) and just multiplying the product by n. However, there is a "type" problem here, since 1-1/p is never an integer, so something like

```
totientRevisited n =n* product  map (\x->1-1/x) (primeFactors n)
```

will not run in Haskell as written.

My question is whether or not there is a simple way to pass to a new type in between the function. I suspect some way of currying, but I've been unable to work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why:

```
totientRevisited n = n * product  map (\x->1-1/x) (primeFactors n)
```

doesn't work.

First, `product` expects one argument (a `(Num a, Foldable t) => t a`) and you give it three (`map`, `(\x->1-1/x)` and `(primeFactors n)`). That's the typical use case for `$`. You lack parentheses around the product too. Let's write this:

```
totientRevisited n = n * (product $ map (\x->1-1/x) (primeFactors n))
```

Second, you have an issue with numeric types. You are dividing `1` by an Integer. Yet `/` takes two Fractionals:

```
Prelude> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

You have to convert `x` to a Fractional. Use the `fromIntegral` function:

```
totientRevisited n = (fromIntegral n) * (product $ map (\x->1-1/(fromIntegral x)) (primeFactors n))
```

You have to use `fromIntegral n` because `(*)` takes two Nums of the same type:

```
Prelude> :t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Now it runs, but it returns an Fractional.

Just take the `round` of the result to get an Integer (again, note the `$`) and you are done:

```
totientRevisited n = round $ (fromIntegral n) * (product $ map (\x->1-1/(fromIntegral x)) (primeFactors n))
```

**EDIT** Precision: I wrote that "`product` expects one argument (a `(Num a, Foldable t) => t a`) and you give it three (`map`, `(\x->1-1/x)` and `(primeFactors n)`)". That's technically not true: you can't give three arguments to a function, because a function in Haskell always takes *one* argument and might return another function that will take another argument... That's what "curryfication" means. Thus, you gave to `product` the argument `map`, yet it expects a foldable, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear, and also justified the presence of $ in Haskell :)

Answer (score 0):

So, your `totientRevisited n = n * (1 - 1/p_1) * (1 - 1/p2) * .. * (1 - 1/p_k)`

Instead of multiplying expressions in parentheses first, why don't you do it like this:

```
x_0 = n
x_1 = x_0 * (1 - 1/p_1) = x_0 - x_0/p_1 = x_0 - x_0 `div` p_1
x_2 = x_1 * (1 - 1/p_2) = x_1 - x_1/p_2 = x_1 - x_1 `div` p_2
x_3 = ...
```

And so on. This is **integer** arithmetic, and it can easily be written on Haskell.

Comment: This may be out of ignorance, but I cannot see how this answers my question.

Comment: Instead of changing the types from `Integer` to `Fractiona`l, `Rational`, `Float` or whatever, I suggest to do it with `Integer` and `div`, changing the formula itself.